# Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000 Scroll Not Working

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have a Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000 with Intellipiont 7.1 installed on Windows 7 x64. The scroll has stopped working before, but a restart or two always seemed to resolve it. I tested the mouse on another computer and it worked. I also tested an Microsoft Arc mouse on this computer and the scroll worked. I have checked everything I could find on google and nothing helps. I have reinstalled intellipoint two times. Tried to change my mouse to another model in the intellipoint settings as suggested in many forums. Nothing.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great. Otherwise, I think my next step is to pitch this mouse and get a logitech at Best Buy tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try installing default drivers, or older models' drivers.